# sublime text 2 and less2css issue

Tags: sublime-text, less

On ubuntu 14.04 I have installed Sublime Text 2 and a plugin named [less2css](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css).
When I try to save, for example `MAIN.less`, file is saved, but isn't compiled into `MAIN.css`. Sublime alerted me that `usr/bin/env node no such file or directory`.

I don't know why Sublime needs this file, file exist and permissions to this file looks fine for me.

EDIT:
the same alert i see when I tray do this from commondline

```
root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# pwd
/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less
root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# ls -la
razem 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 oskar oskar 4096 wrz 21 15:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 oskar oskar 4096 wrz 21 15:06 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oskar oskar   42 wrz 21 16:23 main.less
root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# lessc main.less > main.css
/usr/bin/env: node: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
```

I had install `nodejs` (the the newest version)

```
root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# sudo apt-get install nodejs
Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności       
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
nodejs jest już w najnowszej wersji.
nodejs zaznaczony jako zainstalowany ręcznie.
0 aktualizowanych, 0 nowo instalowanych, 0 usuwanych i 0 nieaktualizowanych.
```

and did `npm install -g less` at the beginning

```
root@mainPC2:/home/oskar# sudo npm install -g less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/1.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/0.1.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
/usr/local/bin/lessc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
less@1.7.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
├── graceful-fs@3.0.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── clean-css@2.2.16 (commander@2.2.0)
├── source-map@0.1.39 (amdefine@0.1.0)
└── request@2.40.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, stringstream@0.0.4, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, qs@1.0.2, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime-types@1.0.2, tough-cookie@0.12.1, form-data@0.1.4, hawk@1.1.1, http-signature@0.10.0)
```

I will be grateful for any help, 
thanks

Comment: Do you have node installed on the system? Did you install Less? What happens when you do (on command line) `lessc MAIN.less > main.css`

Comment: root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# pwd

/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less

root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# ls -la

razem 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 oskar oskar 4096 wrz 21 15:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 oskar oskar 4096 wrz 21 15:06 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oskar oskar   42 wrz 21 16:23 main.less

root@mainPC2:/home/oskar/WORK/__MY/_v10/less# lessc main.less > main.css

/usr/bin/env: node: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu


so it is exactly the same.


but commondline say my "less is the newest version" when I typing apt-get install less

Comment: @OskarKosowski `less` is a different command, not related to CSS or node. Try `sudo apt-get install nodejs`. Also, please do not post command output in comments. Edit the question to add it.

Comment: After you install node correctly, do `sudo npm install -g less`

Comment: I think the problem is that the Ubuntu package names the node program `nodejs` instead of `node`. Try `sudo ln -s $(which nodejs) /usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: @muru - it works!!!, thank you, now only from commonline but works!
I will try reinstall sublime and share with you if this solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Renaming the `nodejs` command to `node`:

```
sudo ln -s $(which nodejs) /usr/local/bin/node
```

resolved the problem in command line, after which I reinstalled Sublime. After this everything work fine.